# SQL: temp table "invalid object name" after "USE" statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I do not fully understand the "USE" statement in Transact-SQL and how it affects the scope of temp tables. I have a user-defined table type in one database but not another, and I've found I need to "USE" that database in order to define a table of that type. Earlier in the query, I define a temporary table. After the "USE" statement, SSMS does not recognize the temp table as a valid object name, however I can still query from it without error.

The skeleton of my SQL query is as follows:

```
USE MYDATABASE1
```

[... a bunch of code I did not write...]

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP_TABLE FROM #SOME_EARLIER_TEMP_TABLE

USE MYDATABASE2

DECLARE @MYTABLE MyUserDefinedTableType -- this table type only exists in MYDATABASE2
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE(Col1, Col2)
    SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM (SELECT * FROM MYDATABASE2.dbo.SOME_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION(param1, param2)) T

SELECT A.*, B.Col2 
    FROM #TEMP_TABLE A 
    CROSS APPLY DATABASE2.dbo.SOME_OTHER_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION(@MYTABLE, A.SomeColumn) B
```

In the last SELECT statement, SSMS has red squiggly lines under "A.*" and "#TEMP_TABLE", however there is no error running the query.

So my question is: am I doing something "wrong" even though my query still works? Assuming the initial "USE MYDATABASE1" is necessary, what is the correct way to switch databases while still having #TEMP_TABLE available as a valid object name? (Note that moving the definition of #TEMP_TABLE to after "USE MYDATABASE2" would just shift the problem to #SOME_EARLIER_TEMP_TABLE.)

Comment: Intellisense isn't infallible. Just like a a spell checker will flag words that are correct (until you add it to its dictionary). SSMS (and ADS) *still* flag `GO {n}` (where `{n}` is a integer) as a error, but it's perfectly recognised syntax by the application that it needs to repeat that batch `n` times, for example. If you're running the SQL and it's not errorring, it's valid.

Comment: Your code is OK. The SSMS just found no `#TEMPTABLE` definition. To infer the definition from `SELECT * INTO #TEMP_TABLE FROM #SOME_EARLIER_TEMP_TABLE` is a bit beyond its capabilities.

Comment: @Serg I should clarify SSMS has no trouble recognizing #TEMP_TABLE if it's before "USE MYDATABASE2", which is how I inferred it has something to do with changing the database. But thank you for confirming it is an issue with SSMS and not with my code.

Comment: The intellisense is likely parsing the document and using the most recently found `use` as a base of reference. Personally I've found the built-in intellisense to be pretty ropey and prefer the Redgate SQLPrompt alternative. It also has no issues with scoping temporary tables.

Comment: Is it valid to say DECLARE @MYTABLE Mydatabase2.MyUserDefinedTableType ?  That would obviate the need for the second USE statement.

Comment: @Duston No, that results in "Cannot find data type MYDATABASE2.MyUserDefinedTableType"

Comment: @Duston the simple answer is no - user defined types are database specific and cannot be referenced externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL `USE` basically tells the query which database is the "default" database.

Temp tables can play tricks on intellisense - unless they're explicitly defined using the `CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable` route, intellisense doesn't really know what to do with them a lot of the time. Don't worry though - temp tables are scoped to the query.

Although I do feel it's worth pointing out: while UDTs are database specific, you can [create an assembly to use across databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/registering-user-defined-types-in-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I do not have write access to the first database, so I imagine that is not an option for me.

Comment: Yeah, it's not an option for everyone; and even when it is an option, I'm not sure it's necessarily recommended